# SQL Transformation Flow Descriptors

Tags: sql, parsing, transformation

I have a bunch of sql statements that populate a table. I would like to know if there are any tools that **describe how each column of the resulting table was obtained** (all the sql transformations that were performed to obtain each column).

For example, this could be a transformation **A.col1 where A.col2=val .. --> B.col1** where B is the final table

This can greatly help me understand large sql codes and also in optimizing them.

Edit : After hunting for a while, I found this https://sqldep.com/sql-wayback-machine. Are there any open source versions similar to it.

Comment: This is sometimes called "data lineage", but the best I could find is some open-source SQL parsers. You'd have to analyze the parse tree manually.